# When I long swipe past the last slide, Swiperjs resets to the previous slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Desired behavior : when swiping right, no matter how much the user drags the slider, the red slide should become the active one.

Current behavior : When the user long swipes past the last slide, the swiper resets to the second to last slide.

Here is a code Sandbox demonstrating the problem : https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-euler-9hejzk

An important thing to note is that the last slide is not full width (30% only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `longSwipesRatio` parameter. It is documented here: [Swiper API](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-longSwipesRatio)

In `SwipeableDiv.js`, you should have something like this:

```
<Swiper
  slidesPerView={"auto"}
  longSwipesRatio={0} // <--- HERE
>
  <SwiperSlide className="cell-content-slide">Slide1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide className="cell-content-slide">Slide2</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide className="actions-slide">Slide3</SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```